# Fit Text box in excel cell?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, web

I am trying to fit a text box in a ASP.NET `gridView` in row data bound. here it is not properly adjusting in the cell.to to fit it properly.

In row data bound I am using

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.style.backgroundColor='orange'");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='white'");
            e.Row.Cells[2].Width = new Unit("700px");
            TextBox txtAddress = new TextBox();
            txtAddress.ReadOnly = false;
            e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(txtAddress);
            e.Row.Cells[2].Style.Add("text-align", "center");
            txtAddress.Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
            GridView1.Attributes.Add("style", "table-layout:fixed");
        }
    }
```

How to fit it properly in grid cell.

Comment: 1000px? 360 px ? those are huge sizes.

Comment: Actually its a comment field ...and client want to see full comment in gridview

Comment: change textmode of textbox to multiline

Comment: done or still not getting what you want

Comment: Not able to do it in RowDatabound...Please an example

Comment: Its not about size ..my query is how to fit it exactly ...it can be any size ..

Answer (score 0):

I am trying this and its working fine ..

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.style.backgroundColor='orange'");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='white'");
                e.Row.Cells[2].Width = new Unit("700px");
                TextBox txtAddress = new TextBox();
                txtAddress.ReadOnly = false;
                //txtAddress.Style = "width:100%;";
                txtAddress.Style.Add("width", "99%");
                e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(txtAddress);
                e.Row.Cells[2].Style.Add("text-align", "center");
                txtAddress.Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
                GridView1.Attributes.Add("style", "table-layout:fixed");
            }
        }
```

100% is mathematically accurate but 99 did the trick for me :)